# How to use adblockers on Wayback Machine?

Tags: wayback-machine

When I read this article on the original site

https://www.fokus.se/minnesord/en-fargstark-miljardar/

with µBlock enabled (filter list at the bottom of this post)

it is not behind a paywall. However, if I disable µBlock, the paywall blocks the article. Fair enough.

**BUT**, if I read the same article on Wayback Machine, with µBlock enabled, the paywall blocks the content

https://web.archive.org/web/0/https://www.fokus.se/minnesord/en-fargstark-miljardar/

**How do I remove the paywall on Wayback Machine?**

---

---

[image: List of µBlock filters enabled]